# There is no option to Choose "Other" as mentioned under YouTube API Node.js Quickstart

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

In the [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs),

> Step 1, (e) says "Select the application type **Other**".

However there is no such entry under the options provided for "**Create OAuth client ID**" in the API & Services page of Google APIs. Which one to opt in that case for Node JS applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google developer console changes faster then they change the tutorials.

select `Oauth client id`

[image]

Then select desktop app

[image]

The results will be the same as creating the old other type app

This will give you a client which id designed to run as a native application on your machine and not hosted on a web server.   Which is what the sample you are following is designed to show you how to do.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped you. YOu will get points as well.